# What's wrong with returning null?

Tags: c#, null

I've recenlty been greeted by **CS8603 - Possible null reference return**, which indicates that my code could *possibly* return `null`. It's a simple function that looks up an entity in a database by id - if it exists, it returns the entity. If not, it returns `null`.

```
public TEntity Get(Guid id)
{
    // Returns a TEntity on find, null on a miss
    return _entities.Find(id);
}
```

My gut feeling says that this makes sense. If the client says "Give me the user with ID 82739879", then giving them "nothing" makes intuitive sense, if no user with said ID exists".

However, the compiler warning caused me to re-think this approach. Should I do something else, other than returning null, if the user ID could not be found? Returning an exception is a possibility, but I don't consider a user not existing to be an "exceptional" state.

Is it "wrong" to return null in this case? Am I overthinking this?

Comment: This question might be helpful, and it also links to other questions you might find helpful: [If null is a billion dollar mistake, what is the solution to represent a non-initialized object?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/413149/if-null-is-a-billion-dollar-mistake-what-is-the-solution-to-represent-a-non-ini)

Comment: @VincentSavard while indeed that link is interesting in general it does not apply to this question - OP *explicitly* said the method returns non null result by not specifying `TEntity?` and compiler simply warns them that there is some *obvious* mismatch between what they promised to return and what code actually does.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Back when I started C#, the `TEntity?` syntax didn't exit. It was implied that any object could be `null`.

Comment: null is NOT nothing... null is a value, not the absense of a value. That's what the warning tells you.

Comment: The problem in your code doesn't quite match the title of your question (and just a "why am I getting this warning" question is probably a better fit for [so]). The warning doesn't show up because there's something "wrong with returning null", it shows up because what you're returning doesn't match the return type you specified.

Comment: It is still implied that any object can be null. It is not implied that every function that returns an object CAN also return a null. In other words, there's nothing wrong with returning null; but there's something wrong with returning null without letting the consumers/clients of the function know they should expect a null value. So, you either let them know there's a chance for the result to be null, or change the function to return a default/empty object (if such thing exists) when not finding a result.

Comment: @BernhardBarker I wasn't asking "Why am I getting this warning?" - I was asking why it exists in the first place, hence if it was wrong to return null. I was simply unaware that returning null is considered a big deal now.

Comment: I see no problem conceptually. If you request to find an object from a map with a key and if the object with a matching key doesn't exist, null is a very legitimate way to communicate that without introducing needless new and non-standard ways to communicate "nothing" as a return value. You could throw an exception or whatnot, but developers can fail to handle that too. Null is a very precise communicator of nothing. I suspect this is paradigm-specific.

Comment: I personally consider throwing an exception to often be a correct approach. It's not always true, but I often consider it to be an exceptional case when the DB is being queried for something that doesn't exist, or else why would the code be looking for it? So I usually create an EntityNotFoundException<T> class which makes it clear that something odd is going on in the logs, rather than hiding "accidents" and bugs that will show up later in unrelated places.

Comment: @Dom An exception is also possible, and I pondered doing that. I think the two are more or less equivalent.

Comment: @MechMK1 I have to disagree. Returning null vs throwing an exception are massively different and completely alter the way the code is architected.

Comment: @jwenting null _exactly means_ the absence of a value.

Comment: So you're telling me you have a pointer to a variable of type X, and when I try to get the variable, it points to NOTHING. How does that make sense? Like giving me a note you said you wrote your name on, and it is empty. Don't give the note at all

Comment: @Suncat2000 no, null can mean a null value. Null and nothing do not necessarilly mean the same thing, weird as it may sound. E.g. I've seen more than a few systems where null was returned to indicate there were no problems during a process, anything not null meant there was an error or warning of some sort.

Comment: @jwenting You should proudly take up your opinion with the language authors because null and Nothing mean the exact same thing in C# and VisualBasic. The symbol _null_ in mathematics and computer science means "containing nothing". It you want to go all Microsoft on us and try to define it as something different, knock yourself out.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

**Why are you getting the warning?**

You have enabled the nullable reference types (NRT) feature of C#. This requires you to explicitly specify when a `null` may be returned. So change the signature to:

```
public TEntity? Get(Guid id)
{
    // Returns a TEntity on find, null on a miss
    return _entities.Find(id);
}
```

And the warning will go away.

**What is the use of NRTs?**

Other recent changes - specifically around pattern matching - then tie in really nicely with NRT's. In the past, the way to implement the "try get pattern" in C# was to use:

```
public bool TryGet(Guid id, out TEntity entity)
```

Functional languages offer a better approach to this: the maybe (or option) type, which is a discriminated union (DU) of some value and `none`. Whilst C# doesn't yet support DU's, NRT's effectively provide that maybe type (or a poor man's equivalent) as `TEntity?` is functionally equivalent to `Maybe<TEntity>`:

```
if (Get(someId) is TEntity entity)
{
    // do something with entity as it's guaranteed not null here
}
else
{
    // handle the fact that no value was returned
}
```

Whilst you can use this type of pattern matching without using NRTs, the latter assists other developers as it makes clear that the method will return `null` to indicate no value. Change the name to `TryGet` and C# now provides that functional style try get pattern:

```
public TEntity? TryGet(Guid id) => _entities.Find(id);
```

And with the new match expression, we can avoid out parameters, mutating values etc and have a truly functional way of trying to get an entity and creating one if it doesn't exist:

```
var entity = TryGet(someId) switch {
    TEntity e => e,
    _ => Create(someId)
};
```

**But is it wrong to return null?**

There has been vast amounts written on why [null was the billion dollar mistake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare). As a very crude rule of thumb, the existence of `null` likely indicates a bug. But it's only a crude rule of thumb as there are legitimate use-cases for null in the absence of `Maybe<T>`. NRT's bridge that gap: they provide a relatively safe way of using `null` to indicate no value. So I'd suggest - for those using newer versions of C# - there is nothing wrong with returning `null` as long as you enable the NRT feature and you stay on top of those `CS8603` warnings. Enable "treat warnings as errors" and you definitely will stay on top of them.

Comment: That may have been done automatically in VS2022. I haven't used VS since quite a long time, so I'm not aware of all the new features. Thank you very much for the hint. Although I still have to ask: Is it wrong to return null? Or do I just have to be explicit that I can return null?

Comment: `null` can cause many problems, therefore it should be avoided. But there are legitimate cases where it can be used. With the NRT feature, C# now requires you to explicitly state when a null can be returned by using `TEntity?`.

Comment: @DavidArno so what would happen in this case if the "Find" method would not find any results?

Comment: @matkv: please do yourself a favor and take the time to read the already existing questions about the issue on this site, like [this one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/373751/if-nulls-are-evil-what-should-be-used-when-a-value-can-be-meaningfully-absent)

Comment: Here are some more: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/370557/do-you-preferer-null-or-default-values-when-forced-to-for-meaningful-necessary/370564#370564    https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/340638/when-do-the-benefits-of-nullable-value-types-outweigh-the-cost-of-null-pointers/340676#340676

Comment: Thank you for the very comprehensive answer now. Things changed so much. The `=>` operator looks weird and out-of-place to me. It makes sense though, since `TEntity? Get(Guid id)` basically "forwards" the call to `_entities.Find(id)`.

Comment: In the absence of `Maybe<T>` you can use `List<T>`. Still lets you avoid null. Just doesn't make as clear that results should be limited to a range of 0 to 1.

Comment: Perhaps emphasize the `?` in the corrected code with a code comment.

Comment: I don't agree that returning null likely indicates a bug. Is it a bug that a search couldn't find any matching items? No. Any function that returns a pointer to an object that doesn't necessarily exist could return null without being a bug.

Comment: @JonathanWood The point is that the vast majority of your code _shouldn't_ deal with possibly null values. Even in pre-NRT code, 99% of the time, you _assume_ a reference will not be null - and a violation of that assumption is a very common cause of software errors. NRT allows you to be explicit about the parts that deal with nulls, and keep the rest of your code clean, while also getting support from static analysis to detect cases where you accidentally turn a nullable type into a non-nullable type without actually guaranteeing it's not going to be null.

Comment: @JonathanWood So if you decide to represent "not found" with a null, go ahead, it's up to you. Just make sure the signature _says so_ (e.g. `MyEntity? Find(...)`). The whole point of the feature is to allow you to constrain the code that _doesn't_ deal with null-values, not to remove null-values altogether (though it's certainly possible and I have used it to great effect). The troubles with nulls are eerily similar to C-style error return codes; if you forget to check for nulls, you tend to get very annoying and hard to find errors. Better to enlist the compiler to help you avoid that.

Comment: @Luaan: First off, I'm well versed in NRT and its purpose, and have been using it since it came out, so no point in advising me anything about that. With respect to assuming a reference will not be null, based on what? If the function logic uses a return value of null to indicate a particular result, then assuming the returned reference is not null would be just plain stupid, wouldn't it? That was my point: Returning null is a valid way to indicate some conditions, and assuming the returned value is not null in this case is wrong.

Comment: @JonathanWood So why are you asking those questions? The answer should be obvious. _We assume a lot more than we have any good reason to expect_. Yes, maybe you remember that `Find` may return null; if you actually try to use the value right then, it's quick and simple to find and fix. But that's not what NRTs are about. They're about how you _propagate_ null values (and particularly, how you usually _don't want to_).

Comment: @Luaan: What are you talking about? I didn't ask any question. I responded David's comment about returning null being a bug, and now your comment about assuming a returned reference is not null. I do not agree with those statements. And, again, please don't advise me on how to use NRTs. I probably understand them better than you do.

Comment: @DavidArno What version of C# are you referring to? Nullable reference types don't exist in the version I'm using. However, I do see a point in using them, if available. In the absence of a type constraint, `TEntity` could be a value type and therefore non-nullable, hence the warning.

Comment: @Suncat2000, NRTs were introduced in C# 8. The feature is turned off by default though and it cannot be used with the .NET Framework (nor dotnet standard I think, but I'd have to check that). To enable the feature, the tag `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` has to be put into the csproj file, or `#nullable enable` placed at the start of a source file. With VS2022, if you target .NET 6, that tag is automatically applied for you, which is likely the scenario for the OP. The issue you refer to of trying to assign `null` to a unconstrained generic type is the error, `CS0403`, which is unrelated.

Comment: @JonathanWood, just to clarify, I say that "the *existence* of `null` likely indicates a bug" (new emphasis). So I method may legitimately return `null` and that's not a bug. But it's a likely source of bugs as it's common to find code that doesn't handle those nulls properly. However, in the absence of discriminated unions, `null` is a useful way of indicating not found/no value etc, so returning `null` is a legitimate use-case. Which is why the C# language team added NRT's, rather than  a solution that tried to prevent nulls.

Answer (score 20):

David Arno already answered your question about the specific warning, so I'd like to address your general question:

> What's wrong with returning null?

Nothing, **as long as the consumer of your method is aware that null might be returned**, and, thus, it is *their* responsibility to react appropriately.

If your language supports null annotations: Use them. If it doesn't (e.g., if you are stuck with a classic .NET Framework 4.8 project), my go-to solution is to name the method appropriately, i.e., `GetOrNull`, `GetIfExists`, etc. Often, I have both (`Get` throwing an exception and `GetOrNull` returning null), if I need to cover both use cases:

```
public TEntity GetOrNull(Guid id) => _entities.Find(id);

public TEntity Get(Guid id) => 
    GetOrNull(id) ?? throw new ArgumentException($"Entity {id} not found.");
```

Comment: The general advice here is good, but if I saw GetOrDefault, I would assume it _didn't_ return null, but returned some default value *of the relevant type* - either one provided as a parameter, a "null object" implementation, or something newly generated. GetOrNull and GetIfExists make much more sense for the case where you are returning a null value.

Comment: @IMSoP: Good point, I've modified my example to use `GetOrNull` by default (no pun intended). Personally, I also prefer `...OrNull`, but I'm afraid that `...OrDefault` is more common in the .NET ecosystem, due to the precedent set by LINQ (`SingleOrDefault`, `FirstOrDefault`, etc.). Granted, LINQ had to do that due to supporting value types as well, which is (probably) not an issue in this case.

Comment: `as long as the consumer of your method is aware that null might be returned` this either doesn't make sense or is always true - if and only if the type is nullable (i.e. not a `struct`), the consumer expects `null`. Same for `GetIndexOf` - the consumer has to expect -1, otherwise it would return `uint`, not `int`.

Comment: @Haukinger: The [contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) of a method is more than just its signature. For example, I know that `String.Substring` won't return null, even though its return type is not a struct. How do I know that? Because the documentation says so. Likewise, I know that `GetIndexOf` will never return -2 (for the same reason), even though this is not guaranteed by the type system. Unfortunately, consumers don't always check the docs (and old C# versions don't support null annotations).

Comment: @Heinzi Yeah, I agree, sure the conract's more than the signature, but the signature is the most basic contract you get, and at the same time the only only you're forced to read. If the consumer doesn't know anything or doesn't want to read the docs, there's only the signature. The docs would say "hey, even though technically I could return -2 or -100, I promise not to return any negative number but -1"... but with the signature alone, he has to be prepared for anything.

Comment: On a side note, if you're doing medical or aviation stuff, you better check the result _even though_ the documentation promises that it won't be `null`... you never know whether there's a bug in the implementation or not, do you?

Comment: @Haukinger: Regarding signatures: True. In theory, the consumer should either check the docs or be prepared for anything. In practice, in my experience, consumer's don't, hence my suggestion to use a hint in the method name. It's just a pragmatic way to reduce the *likelyhood* of NullReferenceExceptions.

Comment: @Haukinger: Regarding checking for unexpected values in critical scenarios: This is a double-bladed sword. Yes, adding an assertion that crashes the component in a controlled way if an unexpected value is returned is a good idea. However, all too often I've seen code like this, written by people who heard that "defensive programming" is a good thing without understanding it: `var a = SomeMethod(); if (a != null) { /* remainder of code */ }` with an implied `else { /* silently do nothing */ }`. This is usually *worse* than crashing with a NRE, since it *hides* the error.

Comment: @Haukinger: In Swift, everything is optional. You can have an optional<Bool> with three values: true, false, nil. And the compare operator compares them appropriately. You can ask "if b == true" (true, not false or nil), or "if b != false" (true or nil). Or "if b != nil" (true or false, not nil). And you can have an optional struct. Important since String, Array, Int, Float are all structs under the hood.

Comment: @Heinzi: Typical Swift code "guard let a = SomeMethod() else { ... } The language requires that the else branch exists and exits the current scope (usually by returning from the function or throwing an exception). Hard to ignore. And without the "guard let", the compiler doesn't allow you to access a.

Comment: @Heinzi Spot on. **Checking** for null returned by something you call usually isn't enough; you need to be able to *do something sensible* when you get null (i.e. fulfill your own contract). That takes a lot more thought, and often that just flat out isn't possible. If you absolutely need the value to have methods or attributes you might as well just blindly access them and get the NRE if you're wrong. It can be worthwhile to check whether something that wasn't supposed to be null actually isn't before you pass it on to someone else though, to move the exception closer to the problem.

Comment: @IMSoP `null` is the default value for reference types...

Comment: @Tvde1 `null` being the default value for reference types is the billion dollar mistake

Comment: @Caleth I fully agree

Answer (score 5):

So as per [This answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/433388/186964), you can make the warning go away by explicitly specifying when a null might be returned.

Think of the caller however - they're still going to need to do a check for null.

I prefer using the Try Get pattern. You return a boolean, with the actual return value you were after as an out parameter, like so:

```
public bool TryGet(Guid id, out TEntity entity)
{
    entity = _entities.Find(id);

    return entity != null;
}
```

For the caller, this can be quite a bit more convenient. It makes it very easy to use a guard pattern such as the following:

```
TEntity entity;
if(!TryGet(id: idIWantRecordFor, out entity))
{
    entity = new TEntity
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        SomeProperty = "Some content"
    };
}

// at this point, no matter what, we've got a usable TEntity
// either one we got from the db, or a default, or a new one, etc.
Console.WriteLine(entity.SomeProperty);
```

Comment: This pattern makes sense when you cannot reliably say whether a `null` returned was an "error signalling null" or an actual value of null, because null is a valid value in that case. So for example on Dictionaries, this pattern makes sense, since null is a valid value to store in a dictionary. As a "guard pattern" it's useless, it does exactly the same in exactly the same amount of code as a null check.

Comment: In fact the guard pattern now has two connected variables, a bool and an item and you have to do extra work to let the compiler and static analysis know that they belong together and that their values depend on each other. With a simple null-check any compiler or tool can trivially find out whether the local variable is null or not and give you warnings about it. Resharper did that years before any notion of nullable objects being a special thing in the C# language.

Comment: And now that C# has pattern matching, you get pretty if-syntax with null-returns too.

Comment: Five years ago, this would have been good advice, But C# has moved on hugely and these days I'd not recommend people write C# in this way. This pattern is much better served these days via `T?` and pattern matching.

Comment: And those 9 lines of code because TryGet() forces me into an if clause are supposed to be better than `TEntity entity = Get(id) ?? new TEntity(Guid.NewGuid());`?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica To be fair, the ternary operator also exists and is extremely commonly used for this kind of thing - `var entity = TryGet(..., out var e) ? e : new TEntity(...);`. If you really expect this exact pattern though, I'd also stick with `??`.

Comment: +1, but worth mentioning `https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.notnullwhenattribute?view=net-6.0` and friends: Try* methods are more general and don't prescribe any meaning to `null`, while allowing you to exploit `null` float analysis at the same time (e.g. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/libraries/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/SortedDictionary.cs#L292). They are essential in scenarios where the result is generic to provide a usable API (in the absence of an `Option` type or similar)

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with null pointers in principle.

What's wrong with older languages is that there is no way to know whether a pointer *could* be null or not. So you have to check whether it's null, even though according to your code it never can be null. Wasting code and time. Of course the one time where you don't check it's Null. The other extreme is when data *can* be present or absent and you have a language that doesn't allow a pointer to be non-null. Then you have to produce a pointer with fake data if the data is absent, just as bad.

Newer languages have "optional" values. In Swift, for every type T there is a type `optional<T>`. So your `TEntity` CANNOT be null. But an `optional<TEntity>` can be null. Normal code doesn't allow you to try to access the data in an `optional<TEntity>`. There is a special "if" that lets you try to extract the `TEntity`, while at the same time reporting success or failure, and if extracting the TEntity failed, then it is not accessible.

The language doesn't allow unnecessary tests - if you have a variable of type `TEntity` it CANNOT be null, and the compiler doesn't allow you to test if it is null. If it is of type `optional<TEntity>` then you MUST test if it is null in some way. So you get 100% safety, *And* you can very easily report that some value isn't present.

```
if let result = something.get(guid: someGuid) {
    // result is a valid TEntity
} else {
    // There is no TEntity, and no variable "result"
}
```

Comment: I like that. My only concern is that two years later, although I was originally sure that the return value can never be null, a new use case emerges where it is possible, and I have to come up with a fake value, so I'm stuck with the worst of both worlds ;-).

Comment: No, if it suddenly can be null, you change the lowest function that might return null to return an optional, and the compiler will tell you the rest. Obviously if it can be null (patient refuses to give their date of birth), that’s not a trivial change. The problem isn’t the null, but the fact that the date of birth is not present, and you have to handle that. Optional values make clear where changes are needed.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: Indeed. I often see code which fails with NPE when it checks `something.isEmpty()`, thinking that `something` is an Optional. And then you get double-bad code, needing to check for `null` first, then for `isEmpty`, and finally getting the value if there's one. :-(

Comment: @EricDuminil One of my most useful functions when I programmed C# was a `public static bool INoE(this IEnumerable)`. "INoE stands for "IsNullOrEmpty", but it had to be short because it was used all the time. Suddenly I didn't have to worry any longer whether a function author had chosen to return an empty collection or null when nothing was found.

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean to get a record by id when that record doesn’t exist? That sounds like an error to me. I have tons of code that tries to get a record by id and then throws if the record is null, because that is the record I am supposed to be displaying or changing, and if it doesn’t exist there’s nothing else sensible I can do.

Throwing an exception is what you should do when you don’t have a way to do what you are supposed to do. Your signature says you are supposed to return a TEntity, are you returning a TEntity?  No, you are sometimes returning a null value.  Either your signature doesn’t say what you want it to, or you should throw.

Comment: Whether a value of type `TEntity` should represent an object of type `TEntity`, a non-null pointer to an object of type `TEntity`, or a possibly null pointer to an object of type `TEntity` is a question of language-design. Yes, the third option is an unfortunate choice.

Comment: @Deduplicator: whether you can make the distinction is a matter of language design, and in C# you can.  A signature of `public TEntity? Get(Guid id)` would say that it can return null, the current signature says it can’t which is why the OP is getting a warning. The OP needs to decide what the function does, and change the code/signature accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

*"In the days of yore,"* functions indicated error-conditions by returning particular values.  Unfortunately, this put the burden upon every direct or indirect *caller of* those functions to "always do the right thing."

As time went on, we realized the value of **"exceptions."**

So: When you realize that *"no user exists,"* instead of indicating this by a return-value (such as `NULL` ...) you treat it as **"an** ***exception."***  Instead of "returning" anything, instead you create an exception-object and throw it up into the air ... expecting someone to "catch" it.

In practice, this works quite well: "ordinary" program logic is able to proceed, simply assuming that *"if I am still here, nothing went wrong."* Exceptional cases are moved to an entirely different path which consists of "throwers" and "catchers."

Any point in the program which detects an exceptional condition can "throw."  Meanwhile, the "catchers" don't have to care where the "throw" actually came from.

Comment: The absence of something, where absence is a valid state, is not an exceptional condition. I think (ab)using exceptions for something like that is a bad pattern.

Comment: @Domi: that id is a guid, I would really question the idea that a record identified by a guid not existing being a valid state.

Answer (score -1):

Just do this, adding `?`
Example:

```
public async Task<TblEstudiante?> GetAsynEstuByID(int id)
```

That's all

Answer (score -2):

I read somewhere that you should always try to separate your valid data variables from the status variables. So using the return value for both data and status is not advised.

Answer (score -4):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with returning null if the business case says the data is optional.
I worked as a senior Java developer in large enterprise for 10 years, and had my share of null pointer exceptions to fix. After a while I realized that the majority of the exceptions indicated there was business use case that we didn't handle correctly, if at all.
For instance our mainframe database would specify that customer date of birth was a mandatory field and would never be null. But it turns out we did not collect this field for the first several years, so some records would have null value. You can't fix this without revisiting the business use case - what should we do with ancient customer data? Hiding the exception with Optional and the like fixes the technical problem but
creates a subtle bug. Long live the NPE!

Comment: I disagree with this. The point of non-nullable types is this: Your business logic says that the date of birth is mandatory, so you add a non-nullable `Date` to your record. Then, you run into problems when importing old data. You discuss your business logic and decide that the date of birth is not mandatory after all, so you change it to `Optional<Date>`. And now you profit: Because the types don’t match up anymore, the compiler will tell you all the places where you are using the date of birth, so you can go through them one by one. Crucially, you don’t need to wait until you run into a NPE.

Comment: In Swift, you _cannot_ get a null pointer exception. The compiler doesn't let you access data referenced by a null pointer. But anyway, what if i don't want to give you my date of birth? It's none of your business (in most cases).

Comment: @gnasher729: You definitely can *ask* my date of birth. It's usually 01-01-1900, 01-01-1970, or 01-01-(CurrentYear - 21).